# Redirect to "finish_sign_up" when Users subscribe with Omniauth Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I installed Facebook signup with the gem 'Omniauth' and now Users can connect with it. And I use Devise in my website.

I want to know how I have to redirection path like finish sign up  after Users are connected with Facebook because they have to fill a form with specific information.

Do I add a new condition in an existing controller file? I created one which names `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`

and the code is:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Facebook') if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.facebook_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

And I try to do this

```
if user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Facebook') if is_navigational_format?
user.thing_you_want_to_check.blank?
     redirect_to finish_sign_up_path

    else
      session['devise.facebook_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a condition that checks whether the fields have been filled out in your sessions controller create action:

```
def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  if user.thing_you_want_to_check.blank?
     redirect_to finish_sign_up_path
  else
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed In!"
  end
end
```

EDIT using the updated code you provided:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

def facebook
    user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

```
if user.persisted? && user.some_field.blank?
   redirect_to # put the path you want them to go to here
elsif user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect user, event: :authentication
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Facebook') if is_navigational_format?
else
  session['devise.facebook_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
```

end
end

The `some_field` should be the field they would fill out at the path you're directing them to. If it already exists, you just want them to sign_in and not have to go to that path. That's why we're checking to make sure it's blank.

Comment: I have added more specific infos on my question above. Please could you guide me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you could add an additional condition that checks whether the additional fields exist inside your `user.persisted?` conditional. If they don't exist, redirect them to the path you desire.

Comment: You mean I have to add                                                         if user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Facebook') if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session['devise.facebook_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end

Comment: I am trying it but I have created column I which names fields with a lot of informations. I name It?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: you mean `some_fields` should be the field they would fill and I migrated a column which names fields to Users with following infos like `rails g migration AddFieldsToUsers date_of_birth:string city:string country:string biography:text job:string  website:string social_link1:string social_link2:string social_link3:string`

Comment: yes--some_fields should check for the existence of the additional information you're trying to get from them.

Comment: and in my omniauth controller I change `if user.persisted? && user.some_field.blank?`with `if user.persisted? && user.field.blank?`but there is `undefined method `fields' for #<User:0x007fcf6f5a0820>`

Comment: it would need to be `user.city.blank?` or whatever the field you want to check is.

Comment: I just do this and it works. Could you tell if I can create an array or add 2 or 3 methods in same. Because if the new User add only city he should come again to give the country next... Or I create validates because when he is on the redirect He has to fill to continue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106815/discussion-between-toddmetheny-and-baptiste-becmeur).

Comment: run rake routes to make sure you're redirecting to the right route